# How to pass the parameters from .m to another .m in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, parameters, nsmutablearray

I am writing the iPhone application and I would like to ask about the the passing parameters in Objective-C.

I create 2 view controller. In the first one, I have a button, when a user press the button, it will call the -(IBAction) pressButton (user-defined), and after 5-6 second (have to process and retrieve the data in the NSMutableArray *), it will display a table. However, I don't know how to pass the NSMutableArray to the table class. Can I do this?

```
// situation
// ---------------------------------------------
// In MyViewController.m

// class variable
NSMutableArray * arr;
- (IBAction) pressButton: (id)sender {...}
// I retrieve the data and store in the arr

// In TableView.m
// I want to pass the arr to here and use
```

I know how to create the table, but I don't know how to pass the parameters from a class (MyViewController.m) to another class (TableView.m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TableView ViewController create NSMutableArray like this

```
IBOutlet NSMutableArray  *PassedArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray  *PassedArray;
@synthesize PassedArray;
[PassedArray release];
```

Now you can pass NSMutableArray value from your Myviewcontroller to tableviewcontroller using this

```
tableviewcontroller *objInstance = [[tableviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"tableviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
objInstance.PassedArray = NSMutableArray;//Here you declare your passed NSMutableArray
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objInstance animated:YES];
[objInstance release];
```

Another method is Declare NSMutableArray *yourArray is global in MyViewController.h and extern those variables in tableviewcontroller.m like this

```
extern NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In TableView.h, declare a method:

   ```
   - (void)doWhateverWithArray: (NSArray *)anArray;
   ```
2. In TableView.m, implement the method to do whatever you need it to do.
3. In MyViewController.m, near the top of the file (outside of `@implementation` ... `@end`) write `#import "TableView.h"`
4. Send `-doWhateverWithArray:` to your table view when necessary.

Function calls are a fundamental part of procedural programming languages like C; message dispatches (AKA method calls) are a fundamental part of object-oriented programming languages like Objective-C.

The nature of this question suggests you're just starting to get into programming (if I'm wrong, please don't take this as an insult--it's not.) I'm sure folks can recommend any number of introductory texts to C or Objective-C, but I'd go further if I were in your shoes.

If available to you, I recommend that you take college-level programming courses, or even enroll in a computer science degree at the university level if you have the time and dedication. :)

Comment: (I'd also suggest you look into learning C fully before starting on Objective-C.)

Comment: Learning C fully? Knowledge of C asymptotically approaches 1. ;)

Comment: Agree with @chpwn.  The question hints at a lack of understanding about the fundamentals of object oriented programming.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Not like C is going to help there, though ;).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to ask how to call another function in another class? I have already import the .h and define the header in the tableView.h. When I call the method in the MyViewController class, it have some error. Would you mind to show the calling statement to me?